# MenuBar doesn't show up in full screen mode

Tags: macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

I'm trying to use the full screen mode in Lion, but I can't get the menubar to show up at all.  I push my cursor up to the top of the screen, wait a second, and nothing.  Some apps will seem like they're trying to do something (e.g., Safari will change what's visible in the toolbar), but in no case does the menubar actually appear.  Needless to say, I really effectively can't use full screen mode this way.  Any suggestions on how to get the menubar to show up?

Comment: Has the menu bar ever shown up for you? Did you just install Lion?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe so.  I installed Lion a few days ago.

Comment: I've seen a possibly related bug when using two screens one above the other -- the app goes full screen on the bottom screen (my laptop display), but the menu bar actually appears at the bottom of the top screen (my external monitor). May just be a coincidence, though...

Comment: How about a computer restart? Just for sanity sake. ;-)

Comment: I'll second a restart - even a safe boot (hold shift). Also, you might fire up the Activity monitor and see if you can see any processes that are not responding or taking more CPU than make sense. Something is obviously hung up, but you might have to dig at it for a bit.

Comment: I've restarted several times (though not a safe boot).  I'd be surprised if it were something like a hang, though.  Everything else in the system is perfectly responsive (even the app in question), and the app *does* seem to respond appropriately to the stimulus (e.g., Safari shows the favorites bar).  So far, ScottishWildcat's suggestion seems closest since everything is fine when I use the laptop without the external monitor.

Comment: Just to be clear - is this happening when there is only one screen or is this the bug where the second screens are having unintended consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue.

Please download the 10.7.2 OS X Lion update (Apple Menu > Software Update).

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4767

> The OS X Lion v10.7.2 Update includes Safari 5.1.1 as well as fixes that:
>
> ...
> Address an issue that may cause the menu bar to not appear in full screen apps.
> ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to force the Menu Bar to show up whilst in a fullscreen app, you can use the keyboard shortcut `^F2 (Ctrl+Fn+F2)` to manually show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced, I think there is an intermittent bug that Apple needs to fix in an update. Sometimes, the menu bar just doesn't appear when you move the mouse to the top of the screen.

There are two workarounds that I'm using at the moment:

1. I've found that taking another application into full-screen mode can get things working again, but this doesn't always work consistently.
2. You can of course use the keyboard shortcut (Control + Command + F) to exit full-screen, but this obviously doesn't help you to access the application's menus while in full-screen mode.